# Angular2 *ngFor animation of pushed away elements

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, ngfor

I've seen many animation tutorials for the entering or leaving elements ("New element" on the image below), but the rest of elements (Element 1 and 2), that are pushed apart usually just teleport to their new location.

[image]

Is there a way to animate the other elements to move away nicely, like depicted in the attached image?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use angular2 [animation API](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) to achieve it.

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/yv9t464AFH7xTcugaHpb?p=preview)**

[image]

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
     <div class="container">
      <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" class="item"  (click)="remove(i)"
        [@anim]="item.state">
        {{ item.name }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aside">
      <button (click)="push()">Push</button>
    </div>
  `,
  animations: [
     trigger('anim', [
        transition('* => void', [
          style({ height: '*', opacity: '1', transform: 'translateX(0)', 'box-shadow': '0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'}),
          sequence([
            animate(".25s ease", style({ height: '*', opacity: '.2', transform: 'translateX(20px)', 'box-shadow': 'none'  })),
            animate(".1s ease", style({ height: '0', opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(20px)', 'box-shadow': 'none'  }))
          ])
        ]),
        transition('void => active', [
          style({ height: '0', opacity: '0', transform: 'translateX(20px)', 'box-shadow': 'none' }),
          sequence([
            animate(".1s ease", style({ height: '*', opacity: '.2', transform: 'translateX(20px)', 'box-shadow': 'none'  })),
            animate(".35s ease", style({ height: '*', opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)', 'box-shadow': '0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'  }))
          ])
        ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: any[] = [
    { name: 'Element 1' },
    { name: 'Element 2' }
  ];

  push() {
    this.items.splice(1, 0, { name: 'New element', state: 'active' });
  }

  remove(index) {
     this.items.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to import `BrowserAnimationsModule`

Comment: Your answer was almost what I needed, and it definitely helped me find a solution I consider perfect. They key I have been missing is, I didn't know that **height: '*'** is a thing. I added margin-bottom transition to eliminate that jumpy animation when removing element and changed sequence into group (perhaps it seemed sequenced on gif, I expect animations to be parallel, but with different duration).
Thanks a lot and here's my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cjCXnuOCrNH9b2I7XnLD?p=preview)

Comment: Here is documentation about `height: "*"` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#automatic-property-calculation

Comment: An up-to-date link to the docs now (`opacity: '*'`):
https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#using-wildcards-with-styles