# Fade in and push bottom animation

Tags: angular, animation

I'm trying to animate a div whenever I press a button.

I have a string list:

```
this.list = [
"Element 1",
"Element 2",
"Element 3
];
```

rendered in this way:

```
 <span style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="add()">Add item</span>
    <div class="wrp"  [@fadeInOut]>
        <div class="si" *ngFor="let item of list">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
```

the `add` function:

```
this.list.push("Element 4");
```

The animation:

```
animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [   // :enter is alias to 'void => *'
        style({opacity:0}),
        animate(500, style({opacity:1})) 
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [   // :leave is alias to '* => void'
        animate(500, style({opacity:0})) 
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

What I'm trying to do, is to achieve this animation:

[image]

When I add a new item to this list, the list is pushed down and then the new element "fade" in from left to right.

Can anyone help me out? It's fine if there is a way to do it by scss.

the problem is also here: [Angular2 *ngFor animation of pushed away elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376006/angular2-ngfor-animation-of-pushed-away-elements)

but the example isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

With a few small changes it works fine for me.

the animation:

```
animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      transition(':increment', [
        query(':enter', [
          style({ opacity: 0 }),
          animate('500ms', style({ opacity: 1 })),
        ])
      ]),
      transition(':decrement', [
        query(':leave', [
          animate('500ms', style({ opacity: 0 })),
        ])
      ]),
    ])
  ]
```

the component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  list = [
    "Element 1",
    "Element 2",
    "Element 3"
  ];
  itemsTotal = 3;

  add(): void {
    this.list.splice(0, 0, "Element 4")
    this.itemsTotal++;
  }
}
```

the html:

```
<div class="wrp" [@fadeInOut]="itemsTotal">
  <div class="si" *ngFor="let item of list">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```